Find $\mathcal{F}$ the complex product formula
For any set of complex function $f,g:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ we have
\begin{equation}\label{Eq22}
\prod_{i=1}^{d}{(f(i)+g(i))} = \sum_{i=1}^{d^\prime}{\mathcal{F}(i)}
\end{equation}
for some function $\mathcal{F}:~\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ and value $d^\prime \in \mathbb{N}$. I want to determine the function $\mathcal{F}$ by expanding the product into a finite summation.
I start with
$$(f(1)+g(1))(f(2)+g(2))(f(3)+g(3))\cdots(f(d)+g(d)) $$ then we need to use the distributive property. The first gives us $$(f(1)+g(1))(f(2)+g(2))= (f(1)f(2)+f(1)g(2)+g(1)f(2)+g(1)g(2))$$
I thought about binomial theorem but I don't see connection because it doesn't have power.

What do you mean "determine the function $\mathcal F$"?  Well, it could be that $\mathcal F(1) = \prod_{i = 1}^d (f(i) + g(i))$, but presumably that's not what you mean.  I suppose you want $\mathcal F(i)$ to consist of products of $i$ "terms" ($f(j)$ or $g(j)$), in which case $d'$ equals $d$ and $\mathcal F(i)$ equals $\sum_{a + b = i} \sum_{\vec a \in \binom{\underline d}a, \vec b \in \binom{\underline d \setminus \vec a}b} f(\vec a)g(\vec b)$, with notation that can be guessed or replaced by other that you prefer.

Sorry for confusion I want to expand the product left to right. It is a finite product so we can expand it using the distribution rule. But we have to multiply out each term
